# Implementing Distributed Distinct Item Sampling in Spark or other distributed frameworks

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, sampling

I am trying to solve the following problem.
I have logs of user visits on a website. Each log contains the following:-

userid(as key) and other information like browser, ip address, date, hour_of_day, lots of other attributes. You can think of all other attributes as "value".

In essence, I have key-value pairs where key is userid and value is a list of attributes. All the logs are in HDFS and there are billions of records/log entries per day each in an hourly folder i.e from hour 0 to hour 23.

A given user can have multiple log entries(multiple visits).

**I want to do random uniform sampling over distinct userids**

My sample size has an upper bound K i.e I want all the logs of K distinct users. I use MinHash(K) algorithm described below

1. Choose a random hash function for this day. This function will remain the same for the rest of day and will change on next day.
2. Hash the user id(x) to get hash value h(x)
3. Pick the K userids with the least hash values and pick all the logs of these K users for this day.

The above algorithm can be implemented for small data (on a single maching) using a sorted map where key is hash value h(x) and value is the list of attributes(including the userid).

As the logs are in HDFS and in Billions, I want to use a distribted framework like Apache Spark/Kafka to parallelize the above algorithm. I don't have much experience with Apache Spark. I have the following plan:-

Step 1) For each hour h_i (0 <= i <= 23) run the above algorithm on the Spark cluster to get all logs of K users with the least hash values for this hour.

After every hour of data is processed i.e we have 24 Dataframes, each dataframe containing all the logs of the K leash hash valued users for that hour.

Step 2) Take union of all 24 hours and then pick only K userids with least hash values and discard the rest.

Can someone guide if at all Step 1 and Step 2 can be performed efficiently in a distributed framework like Spark/Kafka?

Regards

lali

Comment: Transform the userid(x) to h(x) and then sort by h(x). Once I've the things sorted, pick all the logs of the first K users in ascending order. This uses sorting. Do you think this is efficient?

Comment: Unclear why you think you'll need Kafka here. Spark can read HDFS data just fine, so what specific issues are you having? You won't have 24 dataframes; you should have one that's partitioned by an hour field, then you don't need to union anything

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for the reply. I wanted views on what is the most efficient way to do the same. Right now, as said in my above comment, I am thinking of sorting the dataframe by h(x) and then take all logs with K least h(x) values

Comment: Yeah, and I believe Spark (or Flink) should be able to do that just fine. Doesn't require Kafka if the data is already in HDFS